# How to stop websites from buffering and auto-playing videos in firefox?

Tags: arch-linux, video, firefox

My system is `Manjaro Linux` with `Firefox 41.0.2`.

When I visit certain websites like [youtube](http://youtube.com) or [HackerRank](http://www.hackerrank.com), they start playing videos automatically. I want to stop these websites from auto-playing videos as well as even buffering the videos unless I want them to do that.

Is there something that works on firefox 41+ on linux?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to U&L. SuperUser SE seems more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install extensions to Firefox:

uBlock for publicity - far better than adblock, not receiving money to let certain ads pass, and using less resources;

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/ublock/

FlashBlock to enable only Flash on the few occasions you want to use it, are superb;

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/flashblock/

You also have Stop Tube HTML5 to stop HTML5 auto-starting videos.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/stop-tube/

In the server side, you also have got a very interesting project to use a raspberry pi as an ad blocker for your network, pi-hole

http://pi-hole.net

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a hidden setting to disable html5 video autoplay.

Go to `about:config` then set `media.autoplay.enabled` to false.

That will at least disable autoplaying. It does not disable buffering but firefox only buffers a small portion of the video.